# programmatically enable a specific appscript for container bound sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-apps-script-api

I would like to programmatically enable a container bound appscript. i can able to create app script via an api and attach to a sheet. problem is if the sheet already have another app script enabled ,that script is working instead of my script unless i specify it on `tools->script editor->select project->enable`. i have created the script via an api. can i enable it via an api?

so far i have this code below. but don't have the code for how to enable the script programmatically. as a side note the below script would work as expected if there is no other app script attach to the spreadsheet.otherwise it is unpredictable

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
#https://script.google.com/home/usersettings
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Apps Script API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments']);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


/**
 * Shows basic usage of the Apps Script API.
 *
 * Call the Apps Script API to create a new script project, upload files to the
 * project, and log the script's URL to the user.
 */
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Script($client);

// Create a management request object.
$request = new Google_Service_Script_CreateProjectRequest();
$request->setTitle('spreadsheet_script 40');
$request->setParentId('11111');
$response = $service->projects->create($request);

$scriptId = $response->getScriptId();

$code = <<<EOT
function onEdit(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('alert 30091');
}


EOT;
$file1 = new Google_Service_Script_ScriptFile();
$file1->setName('spreadsheet script 56');
$file1->setType('SERVER_JS');
$file1->setSource($code);

$manifest = <<<EOT
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "exceptionLogging": "CLOUD",
    "oauthScopes": [
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments"
  ]
}
EOT;
$file2 = new Google_Service_Script_ScriptFile();
$file2->setName('appsscript');
$file2->setType('JSON');
$file2->setSource($manifest);

$request = new Google_Service_Script_Content();
$request->setScriptId($scriptId);
$request->setFiles([$file1, $file2]);

$request1=new Google_Service_Script_Version();
$request1->setScriptId($scriptId);
$request1->setVersionNumber(1);
$service->projects_versions->create($scriptId,$request1);

$request2=new Google_Service_Script_DeploymentConfig();
$request2->setScriptId($scriptId);
$request2->setVersionNumber(1);

$service->projects_deployments->create($scriptId,$request2);

$response = $service->projects->updateContent($scriptId, $request);
echo "https://script.google.com/d/" . $response->getScriptId() . "/edit\n";
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i have already gone through this. My problem is if multiple appscript file in same spreadsheet have onEdit triggers why both of the triggers not work?instead only one onEdit trigger work.

Comment: Every function has to have a different name.

Comment: You will need to combine them into one function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what if the same spreadsheet is  connected to another google project which also inject app script to the same spreadsheet which has onEdit in it.is that a bug?

Comment: I should have said that every function in a project must have a different name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will definitely check this with a different google project and let you know